# Concavity of distance to the boundary of Riemannian manifold

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convexity

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold with non-empty boundary $\partial M$. Assume (for simplicity) that $M$ is compact. Let $M$ be locally geodesically convex, i.e. any shortest path in $M$ connecting any two sufficiently close points is a geodesic in $M$ (namely satisfies the standard second order ODE).

> Assume in addition that $M$ has non-negative sectional curvature. Is it true that the function on $M$ given by $$x\mapsto dist(x,\partial M)$$
> is concave, i.e. its restriction on any shortest path in concave?

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: When $M$ is convex this is theorem 8.10 in Cheeger-Ebin book "Comparison theorems in Riemannain geometry".

Comment: @IgorBelegradek : Many thanks.  It practically answers my question.  I have to read the proof. Probably it gives everything.